# Italian Cadastre - WMS in leaflet in r

Tags: r, wms, r-leaflet

I have been trying for some time now leaflet in R to be able to view the Italian cadastre, precisely I am interested in the land cadastre.

This is the code I am using, but with zero success.

```
# Load the libraries
library(leaflet)

# Create the Leaflet map
mymap <- leaflet() %>%
  addTiles() %>% 
  setView(lng = 12.492373, lat = 41.890251, zoom = 14) # Adjust the coordinates and zoom level accordingly

# Add the WMS layer using addWMSTiles from leaflet
wms_url <- "https://wms.cartografia.agenziaentrate.gov.it/inspire/wms/ows01.php"
wms_layer <- addWMSTiles(
  map = mymap,
  baseUrl = wms_url,
  layers = "CP.CadastralParcel",
  options = WMSTileOptions(format = "image/png", transparent = TRUE),
  attribution = "© Agenzia delle Entrate - Riconoscimento CC-BY 4.0"
)

# Display the map
mymap
```

I leave here the link to get the information to be able to add WMS to leaflet

https://www.agenziaentrate.gov.it/portale/it/web/guest/schede/fabbricatiterreni/consultazione-cartografia-catastale/servizio-consultazione-cartografia

I hope that i provide you all the information, but you need more, i am here.

Thanks